# How to compare two Array List of different types?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have taken a Class type ArrayList (1 String, 6 int) and now I have to compare the numbers with another array. How can I compare them?

```java
    ArrayList<customer> customerArray= new ArrayList<customer>();   
    ArrayList<Integer> storeRandomNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] splitTheArray =new int[10];
    int t=0;

    public void buyTickets()
    {               
        customerArray.add(new customer("Jon", 4, 6, 7,8, 7,9));
        customerArray.add(new customer("Adams", 4, 4, 4,4, 4,4));

        System.out.println(customerArray);
    }        

    public void pickLottery()
    {
        Random rand1 = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i< 6; i++)
        {
            storeRandomNumbers.add(rand1.nextInt(8)+1);

        }
        System.out.println(storeRandomNumbers);
        //splitTheArray[t++] = Integer.parseInt(customerArray[0][1]);

        System.out.println("Common Items: "+(customerArray.stream().filter(storeRandomNumbers::contains).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }


}
```

I expected the customerArray numbers would be compared with storeRandomNumbers and give the matching numbers

Comment: Write your own compare method `boolean compare(Integer x, Customer y) `. You could also write this as a static method of the Customer class

Comment: I need to match the numbers i have inserted in my customerArray with the another integer array storeRandomNumbers.

Comment: Since it is a lottery, they should not be repeating but you entered : " 4, 4, 4,4, 4,4". For your scenarios,  Do you need to be able to enter duplicate values ? I'm asking because it is changing the solution method a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method in your customer class to check customer's numbers with the list of lottery number. Assuming this method will return "true" if all of customer's numbers are a match for the lottery numbers, "false" otherwise.

```
public boolean containsLottery(List<Integer> lotteryList)
{
        boolean result= false;// default result is false
        // implement your solution for finding if the numbers are a match
        return result;
}
```

All you have to change on the main code is this part:

```
List<customer> CommonList = (customerArray.stream().filter(x-> x.containsLottery(storeRandomNumbers)).collect(Collectors.toList())) ;
```

I tested it on my version of customer class and this **.filter(x-> x.containsLottery(storeRandomNumbers))** part seems to work.  Try it and let me know how it goes.